Toyota Matrix 2010 1.8L in limp mode. No throttle response. Error code P2118
Error code P2118. Intermittent no throttle response, sometimes it works fine, sometimes it goes into limp mode. The first incompetent shop replaced the gas pedal assembly, twice, then another shop said the electronic throttle body was bad. I replaced that and no change. I figured it must be a bad wire somewhere. I tested continuity between gas pedal connector and ECU connectors (all good) and between throttle body connector and ECU connectors (all good). These test were done while the car was in limp mode. I pulled on all the connectors while testing for continuity and everything was fine. So now my thought is bad ECU. I get 0 volts on +BM with my scanner when car is in limp mode and ~13V when it's not. Fuse is good and I get 13V on +BM ECU pin connector with DVOM when in limp mode AND 5V at throttle body connector Reference Voltage for the TPS. So, long story short, all the wires are good, throttle body good, gas pedal sensor good, bad ECU? Someone convince me I'm right before I go down the replace CPU route (and of course burst my bubble if I'm not). Thanks!
